# In Visual Studio Solution Explorer why would a solution name be localhost and not the solution name?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In Visual Studio’s solution explorer why and how would the name of the project be localhost and not the name of the project?

When opening a solution and viewing the project in the solution explorer it’s name is LocalHost with the port number. How does this occur? (usually I’ve always seen the solution name)

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have the same question. To put it in simple words: Why do some solutions automatically get their folder name as the solution name and some get name that starts with 'localhost_'? What is the reason? I got so much used to the VS automating my solution's name that this struck me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can `rename your solution` and `save your solution name`, localhost because she have not name

Comment: That is true; but there has to be another why. The solution I'm viewing from TFS shows Localhost from one user and the appname for another and I'm wondering the reason. Thanks